# How can I add certain ClipPath to every page in flutter by writting the code, one time?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-clippath

```
ClipPath(
        child: Container(
          height: 200,
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              colors: [Color(0xFF7CB342), Color(0xFFDCEDC8)],
            ),
          ),
          child: Center(child: Text('mainPage')),
        ),
      ),
```

I want to apply this code to every pages that will open in my app, How can i do it?

Comment: Create a widget

Comment: Create a  widget and take a child widget, This will act as a wrapper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a **widget** like this:

```
class ClipWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget? childWidget;

  const ClipWidget({Key? key, this.childWidget}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ClipPath(
      child: Container(
        height: 200,
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            colors: [Color(0xFF7CB342), Color(0xFFDCEDC8)],
          ),
        ),
        child: childWidget),
      );
  }
}
```

and use it like:

```
return ClipWidget(childWidget:const Center(child: Text('mainPage')));
```